# How to add extras to manifest-declared intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have added Nougat shortcuts to my Android app but all of the shortcuts want to start the same activity, but with a different parameter (then, the activity decides which fragment to add)

So, in the `res\xml-v25\shortcuts.xml` file, I have 4 `shortcut` elements described, they all have the same intent

```
<intent
    android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:targetClass="com.example.MyActivity"
    android:targetPackage="com.example"
/>
```

So how do I pass a bundle with extras to that activity?
I tried with `<meta-data>`, `<data>` and one more thing, I forgot what it was, but the `intent` in `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` always comes empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/feature_1"
        android:shortcutId="feature_one"
        android:shortcuDsaibledMessage="Disabled"
        android:shortcutShrotLabel="Feature 1"
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.example.MyActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.example"
         <!-- <extra -->
              <!-- android:name="action" -->
              <!-- android:value="feature_1"/> -->
        </intent>
    <shortcut>
    // then 3 more shortcuts like this with feature 2, 3 and 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why, but @venimania 's answer didn't help me, maybe I was doing something wrong. I was able to resolve my problem by using a custom defined action of my own:

```
<intent
        android:action="com.example.FEATURE_ONE"
```

and then in `onCreate`

```
String action = getIntent().getAction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add one *extra* for each shorcut so when you receive the intent in your activity you can filter by that: for example:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <shortcut
    android:shortcutId="action1"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/compose_icon"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_long_label1"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/compose_disabled_message1">
    <intent 
    android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:targetClass="com.example.MyActivity"
    android:targetPackage="com.example"/>
    <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
         here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
         they launch this shortcut. -->
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
    <extra
            android:name="accion"
            android:value="action_1_fragment1" />
  </shortcut>
  <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
</shortcuts>
```

And then within your activity:

```
String action = getIntent().getStringExtra("accion");
if(action.equals(ACTION_1))
     //Do action 1
else
     //do action 2
```

Comment: unfortunately, when I add `extra` to the intents in the shortcuts, the shortcuts dont even show up when I long press the icon. To verify that this is really the case, I commented out the `extra` part and built again and the shortcuts showed up. Somehow android doesnt want me to pass extras... I will try with custom categories

Comment: oh I think I've added the `extra` node inside the intent. Will try placing it outside of it! That might solve it

Comment: nope, doesnt work and I tried adding `<categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />` as well - btw do you know what this is used for and should it always be "android.shortcut.conversation"?

Comment: The extra should be place inside the intent, category is not necessary! have you add '<meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
  android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />' to your launcher activity